# Python tkinter Text to Border issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a little GUI Program in Python with tkinter.
I now have issues with the vertical alignment and spacing around Text and Label widgets.
There are two cases.

### Case one

Vertical Spacing between Text widget and its border/highlight as you can see with the first 3 Text widgets. Even if I use pady it gets bigger in an uneven way

### Case two

The vertical alignment from a Label to a Text widget is also off. Here I don't know how to influence it at all.

I'm running this on (manjaro) linux.

[Screenshot of the minimal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD7ST.png)

```
import tkinter as tk


class GuiTest():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.wm_title("GUI Test")
        root.geometry("800x600")
        root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')

        baseinfo = tk.Frame(root, padx=10, pady=10)
        baseinfo.grid(row = 4, column=4, sticky='EW')

        self.loc = tk.Text(baseinfo, width=10, height=1, bd=0, highlightthickness=1, font=("Courier", "14"))
        self.loc.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.year = tk.Text(baseinfo, width=15, height=1, bd=1, highlightthickness=1, font=("Courier", "14"))
        self.year.grid(row=1, column=2)


        self.typ = tk.Text(baseinfo, width=10, height=1, bd=0, highlightthickness=1, font=("Courier", "14"), pady='10')
        self.typ.grid(row=2, column=1)


        tk.Label(baseinfo, text="Label").grid(row=3, column=3)

        self.col = tk.Text(baseinfo, width=15, height=1, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, font=("Courier", "11"))
        self.col.grid(row=3, column=4)


        self.loc.insert('end', "Test")
        self.year.insert('end', "another Test")
        self.col.insert('end', "Color")
        self.typ.insert('end', "More Text")
        self.col.configure(background='red')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GuiTest(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

If there are any big NoNos in the code, let met know, I'm still a beginner with tkinter.

Thank you

Comment: You are using `pady='10'`, how do you expect it to even **height** as the one without?

Comment: @stovfl I don't understand what you mean. It only shows, that pady is working (so top and bottom 10pc more) but that there is still not an even space top and bottom

Comment: You have different `bd` for the first three `Text` widgets.  And you can add `padx` on the `Label` widget.

Comment: @nuTux ***not an even space top and bottom***: It's your hardware, see [reply.it](https://repl.it/repls/SuperImpossibleParallelprocessing)

Comment: @stovfl Ah shit, thank you for pointing this out, now the real search begins xD

Answer (score 0):

as by @stovfl pointed out
it was a problem of my system and not of the code.
It worked fine on [reply.it](https://repl.it/repls/SuperImpossibleParallelprocessing)